# How to retrieve data from jQuery.Post() in PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I am currently trying to send a string to a to a php script which will eventually return a JSON  file.
Here is code i'm using to send the string:

```
var str = "testString";    
$.post("php/getTimes.php", str,
    function(data){
            console.log(data.name);
        console.log(data.time);
    }, "json");
```

In the 'getTimes' php file I am simply trying to receive the 'str' variable I am passing. Any ideas how to do this? It seems like it should be pretty simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to name attributes in [POST](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) `data` either with serialized string:

```
var data = "str=testString";
$.post("php/getTimes.php", data, function(json) {
    console.log(json.name);
    console.log(json.time);
}, "json");
```

or with map:

```
var data = {
    str : "testString"
};

$.post("php/getTimes.php", data, function(json) {
    console.log(json.name);
    console.log(json.time);
}, "json");
```

To handle this variable in PHP use:

```
$str = $_POST['str'];
```

Comment: And then just use '$_POST['str']' to get it on the other side?
Thank you so much for your quick reply!

Comment: Yep! But I suggest to use a map. It will be a bit simplier ;)

Comment: You sir, are a gentleman and a scolar. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

In getTimes.php:

```
<?php   
$var = $_POST['string']; // this fetches your post action
echo 'this is my variable: ' . $var; // this outputs the variable
?>
```

Also adjust:

```
$.post("php/getTimes.php", str,
```

to

```
$.post("php/getTimes.php", { string: str },
```

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :) Now you only need to vote one of the two answers ;-)