# Jquery pass variable to post without form?

Tags: jquery

In my superuser page for delete and modify my users I done in this way

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <td>USERID</td>
       <td>NAME</td>
       <td>AGE</td>
       <td>DELETE</td>
       <td>MODIFY</td>
    </tr>

    <?php

    $base_url = 'this_page.php';

    $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {


    $btn_del = "<input type='button' ";
    $btn_del .= "onClick=\"location.href='" . $base_url . "&action=Delete&id=$row[userid]'\" ";
    $btn_del .= "class='deluser' />";

    $btn_mod = "<input type='button' ";
    $btn_mod .= "onClick=\"location.href='" . $base_url . "&action=Modify&id=$row[userid]'\" ";
    $btn_mod .= "class='moduser' />";

    echo "<tr>\n";
        echo "<td>" . $row['userid'] . "</td>\n";
        echo "<td>" . $row['user'] . "</td>\n";
        echo "<td>" . $row['age'] . "</td>\n";
        echo "<td>" . $btn_del . "</td>\n";
        echo "<td>" . $btn_mod . "</td>\n";
    echo "</tr>";


    }

</table>


    <?php

    switch ($_GET['action']) {

    case "Delete":

        // call delete method of user class
        $obj->DeleteUser($_GET['idric']);

        echo "<script>";
        echo "document.location.href=\"$base_url\"";
        echo "</script>";

        break;

    case "Modify":

        // call modify method of user class
        $obj->ModifyUser($_GET['idric']);   

        echo "<script>";
        echo "document.location.href=\"$base_url\"";
        echo "</script>";

        break;

    }               

    ?>
```

This way works decently, but I'd like to do something more elegant, perhaps using jquery post and / or ajax.

Until now I have used jquery passing data through forms (for validate).

```
// # Form Submit
$(".Form").submit(function( event ) {

event.preventDefault();

$.post("action.admin.php", {

  name: $("#name").val(),
  age: $("#age").val(),
  userid: $("#userid").val()
  },
});
```

How could I do to pass my data to action.php (in this case, $userid) without using a form with jquery post?

```
// # click
$(".deluser").click(function( event ) {

 event.preventDefault();

$.post("action.php", {
??
??
```

Thanks

Comment: Same way? Add the variables in a key/val pair as you've done.

Comment: Possibly sent via url itself, adding & with each data as key<>value pair..

Comment: @ram - Sorry u can tell me how?

Comment: pls refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10462812/how-to-retrieve-data-from-jquery-post-in-php

Answer (score 2):

Use data parameter

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: {
      // Your data here
  },
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not actually using the `form` to build the values (as you would with, say, the `.serialize()` function).  Take a look at your code:

```
$.post("action.admin.php", {
  name: $("#name").val(),
  age: $("#age").val(),
  userid: $("#userid").val()
});
```

Each key/value pair has an explicit key and then gets its value from `$('#someElement').val()`.  None of it relies on the `form` tag.  Those elements (`#name`, etc.) can exist anywhere on the page with those `id` values and this would still work.

You can use any value you'd like in this manner:

```
$.post("action.admin.php", {
  name: $("#name").val(),
  age: 'someString',
  userid: aVariableInitializedSomewhereElse
});
```

Comment: &action=Modify&iduser=$row[userid] is not correct. How could I define iduser=$row[userid] for get this in name: $("#name").val()? Thanks